# Inject Spring Data Repository in EJB

Tags: java, jpa, dependency-injection, ejb, spring-data

I am building a Web project running in Weblogic 12c (EE 6), is a Web App, I have configured the project with:

JSF 2 + EJB 3 + Spring Data

I have some repo like this:

```
public interface ColectorRepository extends JpaRepository<PEBTable, Integer>{

    @Query("select t from PEBTable t where t.id >= ?1 and t.id <= ?2")
    public List<PEBTable> findByRange(Integer a, Integer b);    

}
```

and also I have this way to call the repo in the EJB, and I don't have problem to call it this way, it is working fine and I like it:

```
@Stateless
public class PEBGenericParser implements PEBGenericParserLocal {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = PEBCons.PEB_PU)
    private EntityManager emPeb;

    @Override   
    public List<PEBTable> getData() {       
        JpaRepositoryFactory jrf = new JpaRepositoryFactory(emPeb); 
        ColectorRepository repo = jrf.getRepository(ColectorRepository.class);
        return repo.findAll();
    };

}
```

What I am looking for? Well, I would like to call the repository in some elegant way, using CDI annotations, Spring annotations, or something else avoiding to use springs xml (spring-config.xml, etc), I like Spring data, but I prefer to avoid all those xml configuration and just keep my persistence.xml as I am doing.

I would like to do , something like :

```
@Stateless
public class PEBGenericParser implements PEBGenericParserLocal {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = PEBCons.PEB_PU)
    private EntityManager emPeb;

    @Inject
    private ColectorRepository repo;

    @Override   
    public List<PEBTable> getData() {       
        return repo.findAll();
    };

}
```

I will to appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Can't you simply @Autowire it?

Answer (score 0):

To make this work in a Java EE environment, you need to configure your CDI container to provide a way to access your container managed EntityManager.

This can be accomplished with the following simple configuration class:

```
public class CdiConfig {     
    @Produces
    @Dependent
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "db_unit")
    public EntityManager entityManager;     
}
```